# Deploying a spring boot web application on oracle weblogic 12c

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, java-11, weblogic12c

Im developing a REST web service using spring boot version 2.6.5 and spring framework 5.x and trying to deploy it on oracle weblogic server version 12.1.3 and java version 11 however im facing errors in the deployment stage on the weblogic console .

Any advice how can i fix this issue ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to WebLogic server  12.2.1.4 should fix the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).